# How to post a tweet when a new file is uploaded onto a directory over FTP

Tags: ftp, twitter, script

I really hope this is the correct platform for my question. I have spent countless hours on Google but I came up empty-handed.

How can I automatically post a tweet when a new file is uploaded onto a FTP directory? I have tried integromat.com but it doesn't really work.

Your input is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is something you need to write code for. Are you a programmer?

Comment: Unfortunately, coding questions are off topic here. You are not going to find an off the shelf solution.

Comment: Questions about [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. You might be able to ask this over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) however.

Answer (score 0):

If your research hasn't turned up a way to do this out of the box, then perhaps the best method is to have a cron job that runs a PHP script to monitor the files in the directory and then invoke the twitter API.  It wouldn't be a particularly difficult project.